# Did Hadrian conspire to kill Trajan?

Tags: ancient-rome, assassination

Some years ago I read a novel trilogy about Trajan's life and in the last book it shows the bad relationship Trajan had with Hadrian, and how Trajan was planning to designate as successor an African general from his legions instead of Hadrian. In the last scene, Trajan is going back to Rome in a ship (in theory to stop Hadrian from causing problems in Judea) and he's poisoned during the trip. It is also revealed that it was his wife and Hadrian that planned his death.

How historically accurate is this?

Comment: See [Trajan's death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajan#Death) and [Hadrian's relationship with Trajan and his family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadrian#Relationship_with_Trajan_and_his_family).